# Variable scope on this returns undefined in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is it that within Google Chrome, if I open the console and put in the following logic...

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.bar );
}

var bar = "global";
foo();
```

...I get `"global"` as a result for calling foo();

But if I place the same logic into a file called app.js within Visual Studio Code, and from the terminal run `node app.js`, I get  `undefined` ?

Comment: Node.js does not create implicit globals.

Comment: Additionally to what @SLaks said: browsers consoles are unique environments with a lot of tiny nuances: if you want to ensure something works as expected - put your js in a `<script>` tag and run.

Comment: ahhh - That may be a good thing if I am trying to avoid implicit globals overall in my understanding of JavaScript. Thank you node.js for preventive measures!

Comment: You should always use `'use strict';`

Comment: In a browser, the global `window` object is the default context for `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In browser

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.bar ); //"this" point to "window" it equals to: console.log(window.bar)
}

var bar = "global";
foo();
```

In Node.js

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.bar );
}

bar = "global"; //implicit declaration variable will be global object's property
foo();
```